# C Socket Programming: Connection refused

Tags: c, http, sockets

When I type the command `./client www.google.com 80` into my terminal, I get an error:

> connect() failed: Connection refused

The purpose of this code is to get the RTT between the client and the server with any URL I put into the terminal.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define RCVBUFSIZE 32

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);
int getAddressInfo(const char* host, unsigned short* port, struct sockaddr_in* sock_addr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in httpServAddr;
    unsigned short httpServPort;
    char *httpRequest = "GET/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        "Host: %s\r\n"
                        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    char httpBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
    int bytesRcvd, totalBytesRcvd;

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Server IP/URL> [<HTTP Port>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    const char* host = argv[1];

    if (getAddressInfo(host, &httpServPort, &httpServAddr) != 0) {
        DieWithError("Failed to get server address information");
    }

    if (argc == 3) {
        httpServPort = atoi(argv[2]);
    } else {
        httpServPort = 80;
    }

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        DieWithError("socket() failed");
    }

    memset(&httpServAddr, 0, sizeof(httpServAddr));
    httpServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    httpServAddr.sin_port = htons(httpServPort);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &httpServAddr, sizeof(httpServAddr)) < 0) {
        DieWithError("connect() failed");
    }

    char request[strlen(httpRequest) + strlen(host) + 1];
    sprintf(request, httpRequest, host);

    if (send(sock, request, strlen(request), 0) != strlen(request)) {
        DieWithError("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
    }

    totalBytesRcvd = 0;
    printf("Received: ");

    struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    while ((bytesRcvd = recv(sock, httpBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE - 1, 0)) > 0) {
        totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
        httpBuffer[bytesRcvd] = '\0';
        printf("%s", httpBuffer);
    }

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    long rtt = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000;

    if (bytesRcvd < 0) {
        DieWithError("recv() failed");
    }

    printf("\n\nRound-trip time: %ld ms\n", rtt);

    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}

int getAddressInfo(const char* host, unsigned short* port, struct sockaddr_in* httpServAddr) {
    struct addrinfo hints = {0};
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    struct addrinfo* result;
    int ret = getaddrinfo(host, NULL, &hints, &result);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
        return -1;
    }
    // Copy the server address information to the httpServAddr struct
    memcpy(httpServAddr, (struct sockaddr_in*)result->ai_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    *port = ntohs(httpServAddr->sin_port);

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    return 0;
}

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage) {
    perror(errorMessage);
    exit(1);
}
```

Anything I should look out for, or consider changing about my code? I am a total beginner.

I am expecting to get the RTT in milliseconds. I have tried putting in different URLs into the terminal, and changing the port number. I am not sure if the issue is with my code or with my settings. I have not edited the configurations of my code at all, so maybe that is the issue.

Comment: Where do you set `sin_addr`?

Answer (score 1):

Having done this ...

> ```
>     if (getAddressInfo(host, &httpServPort, &httpServAddr) != 0) {
>         DieWithError("Failed to get server address information");
>     }
> ```

... subsequently doing **this** is counterproductive:

> ```
>     memset(&httpServAddr, 0, sizeof(httpServAddr));
> ```

.  You've just wiped out the address information you retrieved.

And **this** is at best useless, though it could also be counterproductive:

> ```
>     httpServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
> ```

You need only set the port.  Keep everything else obtained via `getAddrInfo()`, which will include the correct address family.

Answer (score 0):

You're zeroing out `httpServAddr` after you're populating it.

Zero it out first, then populate.

```
const char* host = argv[1];

memset(&httpServAddr, 0, sizeof(httpServAddr));
if (getAddressInfo(host, &httpServPort, &httpServAddr) != 0) {
    DieWithError("Failed to get server address information");
}

if (argc == 3) {
    httpServPort = atoi(argv[2]);
} else {
    httpServPort = 80;
}
httpServAddr.sin_port = htons(httpServPort);

if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
    DieWithError("socket() failed");
}
```

Comment: Even better, if you pass `argv[2]` to `getaddrinfo()` and let it output a populated `sin_port`, then you wouldn't have to assign `httpServAddr.sin_port` manually after `getAddressInfo()` exits, and you can get rid of the `httpServPort` variable altogether. For example: `const char* host = argv[1]; const char* port = (argc >= 3) ? argv[2] : "80"; ... getAddressInfo(host, port, &httpServAddr)` ... `int getAddressInfo(const char* host, const char* port, struct sockaddr_in* httpServAddr) { ... int ret = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &result); ... }`